# How can I delete a PROXMOX cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, system-administration, proxmox

I have created a cluster on Ubuntu proxmox node ("node01")

`pvecm create cluster1`

This is the output of `pvecm status` (i changed my ip address to 1.1.1.1 for security purposes)

```
root@node01:~# pvecm status
Quorum information
------------------
Date:             Thu Jul  9 09:41:47 2020
Quorum provider:  corosync_votequorum
Nodes:            1
Node ID:          0x00000001
Ring ID:          1/8
Quorate:          Yes

Votequorum information
----------------------
Expected votes:   1
Highest expected: 1
Total votes:      1
Quorum:           1  
Flags:            Quorate 

Membership information
----------------------
    Nodeid      Votes Name
0x00000001          1 1.1.1.1 (local)
```

However I want to **completely remove it**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I remember creating my Proxmox cluster using the GUI, and honestly ... I have never removed the cluster that I currently have working, but this information may be of use to you.

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cluster_Manager#_remove_a_cluster_node

https://gist.github.com/ianchen06/73acc392c72d6680099b7efac1351f56

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSg-aeQ5gT8

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/removing-deleting-a-created-cluster.18887/